# What is the value of these large, gray resistors?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, resistors

I’m by no means an electronics repair person nor am I an electrician or expert at these types of things. I do, however, like to take things apart to see how they work(ed) when something fails. Usually I get lucky and Google search my findings (the suspected part that has failed) and order a new one.

This time I haven’t been so lucky, or maybe I’m just getting older.

Currently I’m in the process of repairing my amplifier.  The +/- cables to the speaker touched and when I opened it up I found 1 of 2 of these resistors had failed. They read 0.1ohm •J or O.1ohm•J I’ve googled, checked Amazon, eBay and cannot find an identical one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you figure out that they'd failed?

Comment: Resistors are about the least likely part to fail, are you sure this is dead?

Comment: If it's a fusible wirewound resistor (likely, given grey body and black stripe) then it's a designed-to-fail part. But usually you would see a scorch mark on the side which I don't see here.

Comment: I figured 1 of the two failed because the other one is cracked and white in color. I took a picture of this guy for an example.

Comment: If you have a picture of the failed device add it to you question.

Comment: Check for other failed parts, too. Shorting out the output can be destructive to a bunch of parts, and I'd worry about the output transistors.

Comment: @Hearth thank you. I have checked the only thing that look’s suspicious is that one resistor in the picture.

Comment: Please add a picture of the broken part/cross section to the question for the archive so it may be useful info for others. And upvote useful answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistors value is just printed on it - 0.1 Ω or 100 mΩ - this was quite simple.

This value could be written in many ways on the part

- 0.1 Ω like on your original part
- 0R1 or 0R10 or 0R100 and also 0.1R, also 0Ω1 and 0Ω10
- could be a colour band code (for instance brown black silver gold)

The tolerance might be 5 % (Yageo uses J for 5 % on it's resistors of such size).

From the size you've given in comments (16 x 5 mm) it can be either 3 W or 5 W. You should not select a component with a smaller body, if unsure it should be bit bigger - so better go for a 5 W component.

If it is a special type (for instance pulse resistant) could only be deduced from it purpose in the circuit - please give more detail about what type of circuit it is.

Could be metal oxide. Wire wound could be seen on the broken part. Maybe no metal layer ressitor.

Thus go for a 0.1 &ohm resistor metal oxide, 5 W rating, look at the body size not being smaller than 5x16 mm and if you have the choice go for a flame retardent type just to be safe.

Comment: 16mm by 5mm I measured in inches but had to convert to mm.

Comment: This is a 300w amplifier. I measured the shoulder but if I measured the body o would say it’s 3mm wide. Would this make it a 3watt resistor? The J means +\- 5w I believe. The resistor next to it (with the bands) I believe has the same value as the grey one with the writing. I’m assuming the one that burned out is a “safety” resistor designed to not catch on fire.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have the given colour code. And yes, 5% is most likely the tolerance. But there are 3 W and also 5 W rated resistors of nearly the same body size. I would go for 5W but you can try with 3 W. There are different series of resistors available and some are specially approved to not catch fire on overload. You could post a link of a candidate and we take a look at it - if you wish to.

Comment: Any links to the resistor would be highly appreciated. Thanks a million @datenheim

Comment: I do not know where you live and which sellers are in your reach, so if I post a link it is not useful. The information provided should allow you to find a suitable component. You can then put a link into a comment and we could check it twice.

Comment: I live in California. South Gate CA

Comment: Here is what I’ve found so far. 

https://specialtypartsinc.com/products/5-pcs-r10-5w5-wwal-vishay-wirewound-resistor-0-1-ohm-5w-5-axial-lead-1

2). Part description BJ-5W-0.1ohm ASIN # B08CXF973F on Amazon. I don’t have a link

Comment: Not convinced, look for something that looks more similar in form...

Comment: That’s the problem I’m running into. When I search up a resistor with brown,black,silver,gold banding it comes back as 0.1 Ω   ±5% (J) that’s the same value as the one that looks burnt out.

Comment: On second view it may als be a metal layer resistor. Could you break the defective part in the middle to see if there is a wound wire, or a thin layer under the gray mold?

Comment: It looks like a “metal oxide”  resistor to be honest.

Comment: Also possible. Look at [this one](https://www.newark.com/multicomp-pro/mcknp05sj010kaa9/res-0r1-5w-axial-wirewound/dp/55T6710), the datasheet. Close to what you have. Maybe the small case variant.

Answer (score 1):

Like datenheim said, this is a 0.1 ohm resistor.

As to its use, I think it's probably there for current sensing.  The 0.1 ohm value would be consistent with wanting to measure or sense a couple of amps of current.

For power rating 5W tops, and probably much less then that in use.  Anything higher than that would probably want chassis or heat sink mounting, Like these (picture is from Amazon),
[image]

or be in a higher temp package (like ceramic/cement)

As for being used for fusing, a fuse is probably cheaper and easier to replace, if in a holder.

Comment: Thank you very much. I’m learning a lot from this little experience. I’d hate to throw away $600 for a simple $2.00 part